# how to set up rails symlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symlink

I want my config/database.yml file to link to my config/databases/local.yml file... how do I do that?

config/database.yml:

```
$ ln -nfs config/databases/local.yml /config/database.yml
```

gives me this error when I try to run a rails server:

```
Exiting
/home/greg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:163:in `resolve_all': undefined method `each' for "ln -s config/database/local.yml /config/database.yml":String (NoMethodError)
```

I've also tried:

```
ln -s config/databases/local.yml /config/database.yml
```

at the suggestion from [here](http://aakashsharmaror.wordpress.com/2013/09/20/creating-a-symlinksymbolic-link-in-rails/)

Comment: Why are you putting your link in `/config` off the root of your drive? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$ln -s /path_to_app/config/databases/local.yml /path_to_app/config/database.yml
```

Comment: yep!  thanks... also, I had it backwards.  You want to put the $ln -s[path1] [path2] in the file you want to change... where path1 is the file you're in and path2 is the file that you want to turn path1 into